# Can only start XCTest on certain condition

Tags: ios, xctest

I encountered an issue when I'm writing XCTestCase. I'm working on a client/server application. User can only start to use the system when the application login to the server which is automatically done in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

     // connect to server and login
     [mySys login:^{ 

         login = YES;
     }];

}
```

All my test case can only be run when the login flag is YES. Because the login may take sometimes. That means I have to let all my tests to wait at least for a period of time (for example, 30 second). It's something like this:

```
-(void)setUp
{
    // Need to be blocked here until timeout !!!
    AppDelegate* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if ( app.login )
    {
        // quit from the block !!!
    }
}
```

What could be the best strategy to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mock login, that doesn't actually call to the server, and takes a completion block with the login already set to YES. I recommend eBay's tech talk on TDD, it covers this very scenario.

I recommend watching the whole video, but here is a link to the specific part: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CeWMxzB1SI#t=1805

Comment: This is great. But it depends on what I'm going to test. If I'm going to test only the logic of the model. This will be a great help. But actually I want to use this test case to test the web service too.

Comment: Well, you can use different unit test methods to call the mock object, or the real one. But usually you wouldn't unit test the web service on the client, because it's just a connection. You can stub the JSON response (or whatever it is) locally.

Comment: The reason why I want to test the web service here is because I'm also the one who create the web service. So that I want to save some time to test it together. If the web service is like for example Facebook, Tweitter etc, then I can basically use the mock or stub method. But in my case it could be too troublesome to do so. Because I have to change mock/stub, model when the web service is changed.

Comment: Well you can't get around the time it takes, implement a mock object to test the mechanism, and use the real object to test the real thing.  But don't run that test every time, only when you do a full system test.

Comment: Thanks.I'll consider your suggestion seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Jeff's answer. I learned a lot from the video. After my serious consideration, I'm still going to test my Rest API in unit test. Mainly because I'm the one who work on the Rest API. I want to test my client and server at the same time. I'll definitely go with Jeff's idea if I'm working on a big project and the models are more complicated.

Finally I'll show my solution: (Wait for a operation finished before starting the test). The idea is to write a base class who inherits from XCTextCase. And I'm using NSNotification to broadcast the login event.

```
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    AppDelegate* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if ( ![app isLogin] )
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onLogin:) name:NOTIFICATION_LOGIN object:nil];

        NSDate* loopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
        NSDate *dt = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];

        while (!self.bCheckIn && [loopUntil timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                             beforeDate:dt];

        }
    }
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:NOTIFICATION_LOGIN object:nil];
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)onLogin:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.bLogin = YES;
}
```